In this design, are the 470μF and 180μF capacitors polarized? If so, can we substitute them with non-polarized capacitors of the same values?
This is the Typical Application Circuit for the XL1509-5.0E. I conducted an online search to determine whether the symbols representing the 470μF capacitor and the 180μF one denote polarized capacitors. However, I encountered conflicting information; one source suggested that the capacitors are polarized based on the symbol, while another indicated they are non-polarized. I am inclined to believe that the capacitors are polarized, as their symbols differ from those typically used for non-polarized capacitors. Additionally, if the capacitors are indeed polarized, can we substitute them with non-polarized ones of the same values? Thank you for your assistance! 

Yes. These should be polarized capacitors. Because these are for filtering.  Here is a detailed article about which one to use where. https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2017/01/evolution-of-capacitors.html

Polarity or not doesn't matter - it's just an inconvenient side effect to certain chemistries (like aluminium electrolytes). The main properties that matter are capacitance, voltage rating and ESR. As well as temperature curves, tolerance etc.

@liaifat85 Looks like a bunch of copy pasta from Wikipedia. I'm not too impressed.

Yes they are polarized.
Generally speaking, you can usually replace polarized capacitors with non-polarized capacitors (of similar value, tolerance and voltage rating) from an electrical point of view.
There may be reasons such as cost, availability, and size that make that substitution undesirable or impractical/impossible.
Aside from practical considerations such as cost and size and availability, some non-polarized capacitors have inferior electrical performance compared to polarized capacitors. For example, ceramic capacitors may lose 80% of their nominal value at a fraction of their rated voltage, whereas aluminum electrolytic capacitors have very little voltage coefficient.

This interfaces nicely with the answer that says non-polarized caps can be replace with polarized caps!  ;-)

@ScottSeidman, you mean mine? Where did I say that?

@ThePhoton -- oops, it says "for a polarized one", and not "with a polarized one".

Some DC-DC converters require a minimum ESR to operate, others don't. If there is no requirement on minimum ESR, you are free to move to better capacitors (film have lower ESR than electrolytic ones). I've seen one application note for a hyesteric buck which added an external resistor in series in case the ESR was too low, so there is always that.
The datasheet for XL1509 hints to minimum ESR, but it's not explicit.

With some odd-ball exceptions, polarized capacitors can only be used if the capacitors are only charged in one direction. All of the capacitors in the schematic satisfy this condition.
If the symbol for a capacitor has a + and -, then the designer intended for polarized capacitors to be used. The two different capacitor symbols used in the schematic, one with two parallel lines, and one with a straight line and a curved line, are often used to distinguish intended non-polarized and polarized capacitors. However, some CAD applications do not make such a distinction in symbols, or if they do make such a distinction, designers sometimes use the same symbol for all capacitors anyway. The moral of this story is that the curved vs straight line distinction cannot always be relied upon.
In addition to capacitance, there are other parameters of capacitors that are of general interest to designers. Effective Series Resistance (ESR) is one of these parameters. It is sometimes important to choose a capacitor with a low ESR. It is sometimes important to choose a capacitor with a high ESR. Low ESR capacitors are useful when low impedance at high frequency is needed. High ESR capacitors are useful when damping of ringing or oscillation is a design goal.
In general, for higher capacitances, higher ESR electrolytic capacitors are cheaper than the same sized (i.e. same capacitance and voltage) ceramic. In the converter circuit in the question, one typically uses a higher capacitance electrolytic together with a lower ESR, lower capacitance ceramic to achieve high capacitance and high frequency response cheaply. But the larger electrolytic capacitor may be replaced with a more expensive ceramic. (Often a multi-layer ceramic for high capacitance values).
As has been mentioned elsewhere, ceramic capacitors are not fully "linear". Their capacitance drops as their operating voltage increases. That needs to be taken into consideration. For "reservoir" or "bulk" capacitors in power supplies, it may be wise to increase the size of the capacitor if ceramic is used.
Although electrolytic capacitors are cheaper than the equivalent sized ceramics (including multi-layer ceramics (MLCC)), there is a use-case for replacing electrolytics with ceramics. Electrolytics wear out from non-use. If a device is to be rarely used, or may go long periods of non-use, it might make sense to use ceramic capacitors to avoid capacitor maintenance.

Yes, the symbols for CIN and COUT indicate polarized capacitors. The symbol for C1, with both electrodes indicated by straight lines indicates a non-polarized capacitor.
You can substitute a non-polarized capacitor for a polarized one in most designs, but the converse is not true. The cases where you can't are when the specific dielectric material of the capacitor matters, for example because of its hysteretic effect or because a certain amount of loss (ESR) is required.
That said, for values above 100 uF a polarized (tantalum or aluminum electrolytic) capacitor is likely to be more economical than a non-polarized (ceramic) capacitor, so there's little motivation to make the substitution you're asking about.

FYI, this symbol has been in use for a long time (maybe a US thing), I think with the curved plate implying "outer foil".  It's polarized if a plus is added.

@TimWilliams Outer foil for tubulars, lower electrode for IC caps, rotor for variables. It is unfortunate that this usage has become confused with polarity.

tl; dr: the big caps are polarized and you should use the same kind unless you really know what you're doing.
The schematic's author is lazy, there should be a "+" symbol on those two caps indicating polarization.
Now, as to whether you could use non-polar caps, you could but there is no benefit to doing so. In fact, non-polar caps of similar value and voltage rating will be larger than polar ones.
Further, the output cap may need a minimum ESR for the regulator to operate properly. If, for example, you replace a polar electrolytic with a ceramic MLCC type, your regulator might not work properly without adding some compensation. Check the regulator datasheet; they recommend specific polarized capacitors for the output.
